# turn on android LED light "enabletorch" for X amount of time?

Tags: led, flashlight

I have the code below that turns ON my phones LED flash every time the button is clicked, but I also need the LED to turn OFF automatically after 3 seconds.  Not sure how to do it, please help.

input type="button" onclick="ipwajax('enabletorch')" value="Turn on LED"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `ipwajax('enabletorch')` enables the LED, and `ipwajax('disabletorch')` disables it, you would want something like

```
<script language="JavaScript">

  function enableTorch(milliSeconds) {
    ipwajax('enabletorch');
    window.setTimeout("ipwajax('disabletorch');",milliSeconds);
  }

</script>

<input type="button" onclick="enableTorch(3000);" value="Turn on LED">
```

Comment: So I just replace the:  input type="button" onclick="ipwajax('enabletorch')" value="Turn on LED"  with everything you gave me above then and it should work?

Comment: it is best to move the function to your topping script block, but it should work even this way.

Comment: Thanks so much, i now need to test this.  really hope it works.  You're the best.